# How to fix CONSTRAINTS stopping me from copying table schema?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that consists of rows to make case barcodes.  I need EXACTLY the same schema now for pallet barcodes.  However, trying to just `SHOW CREATE` of the `caselabels` table, changing the name and a few column names, does not work.

Here is the CREATE script -

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[caselabels](
    [idx] [int] IDENTITY(42,1) NOT NULL,
    [imageFile] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [jobId] [nvarchar](50) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__workO__47DBAE45]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [triggerStatus] [nvarchar](5) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__trigg__48CFD27E]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [workOrder] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [t_stamp] [datetime2](0) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__t_sta__49C3F6B7]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [lotCode] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__lotCo__4AB81AF0]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [expDate] [nvarchar](20) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__expDa__4BAC3F29]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [qty] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabels__qty__4CA06362]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [gtinUL] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__gtinU__4D94879B]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [gtinUC] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__gtinU__4E88ABD4]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [prodNumber] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__prodN__4F7CD00D]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [prodDesc] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__prodD__5070F446]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [prodBrand] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__prodB__5165187F]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [prodSKU] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__prodS__52593CB8]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [prodSize] [nvarchar](45) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__prodS__5441852A]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [dataMatrix] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [startingADCaseCount] [int] NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_palletlabels_idx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idx] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I am just trying to change the name of the table to palletlabels, and the column startingADCaseCount to startingADPalletCount.  Note I already changed the `CONSTRAINT[PL_caselabels_idx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` to `CONSTRAINT [PK_palletlabels_idx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

However, I still get these errors -

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 11
There is already an object named 'DF__caselabel__workO__47DBAE45' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
Msg 15233, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addextendedproperty, Line 74
Property cannot be added. Property 'MS_SSMA_SOURCE' already exists for 'dbo.caselabels'.
```

I look at the first constraint `[DF_caselabel_workO-47DBAE45]` under `caselabels` and I see this

```
USE [AntiDiversion]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[caselabels] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__caselabel__workO__47DBAE45]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [jobId]
GO
```

which seems to just be the same as the `DEFAULT (NULL)` in the table creation already.  Every rows constraint is like this.  Is it ok to just get rid of the `CONSTRAINT [DF_caselabel_....]` sections?

Given the second error is based on the first, I think solving this constraint issue will solve the second error message as well, but what of the third?  I am clueless on that.

Using SQL SERVER 2014.

Comment: You simply need to rename your constraints. 'DF__caselabel__workO__47DBAE45' is an autogenerated name...either give it a sensible, unique name, or a unique name of any kind.

Comment: Also, I don't know of any reason for `Default (Null)` - if you add a row to a table and don't specify a value for a particular field, that field is set to `Null`.  That's SQL Server's "default default", so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your table definition, you should be okay removing the explicit names and just have `FieldName Null`, `FieldName2 Not Null`.

I typically don't name my `Null` / `Not Null` constraints.

Comment: Yea this is a table someone else made that I need to copy schema wise.  I wasn't sure either, and I wasn't sure just renaming the constraints would copy them or anything.  I don't see the need to name `Null`-ish constriants.

Comment: And see my comment on your original post regarding `Default (Null)`.